# Have a mysqldump with Indexes. How do I import it by disabling them?

Tags: database, mysql

I am trying to import a large database but because there's an index, it is taking forever to import the database. I tried copying the raw files to a different machine but for some reason, the largest table is not being read giving me an error: `can't read file: 'tablename.MYD`. So I mysqldumped my old database but it did so with an index. I cannot do it again because it takes a really long time.

I am trying to import the database but am not sure how to do it without indexes. I thought adding an index after import will be much faster. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the indexes and import from a dump file:

`alter table tablename disable keys`

And then when the import is done:

`alter table tablename enable keys`

Although copying the file in the manner you mentioned should work. You just have a permission error. On the shell do:

`chown mysql.mysql tablename.*` and then restart your database. (make sure you are in the folder the table exists at when you use that command) That should fix the issue.

**Edit:** clarified where you should use the command

Comment: Hello sorry for the VERY late comment. but I have the same issue as the OP and was searching on SO for a solution before asking. I have a question, would your solution affect the query speed later on or not? thanks.

Comment: when you enable keys the indexes will be rebuilt. So no the future query speed should not be affected.

Comment: hmmm so index rebuilding will take time then right? I mean the only difference is that at the place of inserts taking too much time, it will be index rebuilding taking that time or a bit less. sorry too many questions.

Comment: the reason to disable indexes on import is so mysql doesn't rebuild them after every insert. If you're doing a large number of inserts this would be really slow. Disabling and enabling ensures they only happen once. As @JohnDouthat pointed out in his answer - disabling and enabling is the default (at least with mysqldump)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I have 4 tables of 150 million rows, and 11 indexes each, on an AWS RDS can't do anything other than mysqldump.

Answer (score 14):

By default, mysqldump produces SQL that disables indexes during mass import and applies them afterward. It looks like this:

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `my_table` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (...), (...);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `my_table` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: To prevent this, call mysqldump with `--skip-disable-keys`